# Android Service does not stop

Tags: java, android

I want to start/stop a service from an activity (like a switch button), but it does not stop.

**MainActivity.class**

```
btnGoToTrack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SendIntentService.class);
      boolean isServiceRunning = isServiceRunning(SendIntentService.class);

      if (isServiceRunning == false) startService(intent);
      else stopService(intent);
   }
});
```

Check if service is online or not:

```
private boolean isServiceRunning(Class<?> pClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (pClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
```

The problem is `isServiceRunning` is always returning me TRUE. I don't know why.

**SendIntentService.class:**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class SendIntentService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.e("D: ", "SERVICE STARTED !");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("D: ", "SERVICE DISABLED !");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"The problem is isServiceRunning is always returning me TRUE. I don't know why."
shouldn't it be:
"The problem is isServiceRunning is always returning me FALSE. I don't know why."?

If it would always return TRUE it wouldn't start the service...

Did you check if pClass.getName() really equals service.service.getClassName()?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. I have answered my own question.

Comment: Ah ok,
I counterchecked it on my device and it worked like a charm.
Despite I forgot to add the service to the manifest in the beginning ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my AVD. I have several versions installed (while developing the app) and I think there was multiple services started.

I have removed all versions from my AVD (Settings -> Apps -> Uninstall app) and restarted the application. Now it's working !